# Can't install Windows.Azure.Storage assembly via NuGet

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-storage

Here is what it shows[image: Microsoft.]:

> Error     Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Data.OData' that is
>   compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.2.2 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.6.0)', 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.6.4
>   constraint: Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.6.4)',
>   'WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables 1.0.470 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.6.2)', 'WindowsAzure.Storage 6.0.0
>   constraint: Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.6.4)'.          0

How to solve please?

Comment: could you run Install-Package Microsoft.Data.OData first and then WindowsAzure.Storage?

Comment: Thanks for update. I already tried this, also got dependecy issues: Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.4' is not compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.5.0 constraint: Microsoft.Data.OData 
(≥ 5.6.0)', 'WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Tables 1.0.470 constraint: Microsoft.Data.OData (= 5.6.2)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once I can't solve this issue via NuGet then I went to another solution. Let say I have two projects - PrimaryProject and Template project. Then

1. I've created new Template project from template "Azure Mobile Serivce"
2. Then install there Windows.Azure.Storage assembly via Nuget. It installs without issues!
3. Close the project and move to its folder.
4. Copying $(ProjectDir)\packages.config and $(SolutionDir)\packages folder to my primary project's destination folders
5. Open PrimaryProject.csproj in text editor and replace there ItemGroup tag contents with Reference children from Template.csproj

Now it works.